# Dynamical systems from an algebraic perspective

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, dynamical-systems, geometric-group-theory, chaos-theory

I am interested in learning more about dynamical systems. Most of my background is algebraic, specifically in group theory/geometric group theory. I was wondering if anyone knew of a reference that gives a thorough treatment of dynamics from a group theoretic perspective?

Comment: Do you mean when the dynamical system is given by a group action? Did you check for instance Zimmer's book?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal! I just found Zimmer's book and it should be alright, though I would want another supplementary text if one exists (Zimmer's book seems a bit hard on it's own)

Comment: I think they all will be hard ("Math is hard" as Barbie used to say). You can also try "Ratner's Theorem on Unipotent Flows" by Dave Witte Morris.

Comment: @BrendanMallery The book Ergodic Theory: Independence and Dichotomies by Kerr and Li might be relevant. I haven't read very much of it myself, but my professor, who knows the authors and has looked through it, says that it is good. As a plus, it discusses Sofic groups, which, perhaps, makes it more relevant given your interest in geometric group theory!